# Como diminuir o tamanho do arquivo .zip gerado pelo DotNetZip?

Tags: c#

Utilizando a biblioteca [DotNetZip](https://github.com/haf/DotNetZip.Semverd), estou zipando uma pasta com dois arquivos de imagem(pode ser JPEG,EPS OU AI) exatamente iguais(para efeito de teste), cada um com 7,25 MB.
Recebo o arquivo .zip com o tamanho de 14,3 MB.

Aparentemente a compressão não está sendo tão efetiva, visto que as  imagens são iguais, a diminuição deveria ser maior, partindo do seguinte exemplo, existe alguma maneira de melhorar a compressão?

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            zip.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestCompression; //Adicionei isso mas não surtiu efeito.
            if (Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(TempZipFiles,UniqueKey)))
                {
                    try
                    {
                      zip.AddDirectory(Path.Combine(TempZipFiles, UniqueKey), new DirectoryInfo(UniqueKey).Name);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            // Salva o arquivo zip para a memória
            try
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    zip.Save(ms);
                    int read;
                    while ((read = ms.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                    }
                    return ms.ToArray();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
}
```

Não sei se tem relação, mas estou zipando essa pasta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E o resultado do arquivo .zip é a pasta + os arquivos dentro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você não vai ter uma grande compressão desse tipo de arquivo ao zipar as imagens. Comprimindo por outra ferramenta ou simplesmente diretamente no windows, você vê uma grande diferença no tamanho do arquivo?

Comment: Fiz o teste exatamente a gora e não... e a diferença é que no Windows fica pior do que via biblioteca...

Comment: Mas será que não existe alguma configuração para resultar no melhor possível?

Comment: Creio que o fato das imagens serem exatamente iguais não muda em nada o tamanho final do `.zip`, porque eu imagino que a compressão seja feita arquivo por arquivo. E, como comentou o @LeandroAngelo, os arquivos `.jpg` já são imagens compactadas por natureza, logo, você não conseguirá grandes ganhos de tamanho ao compacta-las.

Comment: @PedroGaspar  entendi ! achava que pela compressão ser através de dicionarios, por ser duas imagens iguais iria comprimir melhor(tipo 50%), mas as duas imagens iguais foram só um exemplo mesmo, o cenário real serão imagens de diferentes tamanhos. De qualquer forma vou esperar se alguém responde alguma coisa, pelo menos explicativa.

Comment: qual o tipo/extensão dos arquivos?

Comment: @RicardoPontual vai ser sempre JPEG, AI ou EPS

Comment: Mas o que você quer de fato? reduzir o tamanho dos arquivos para armazenar, sem alterar os originais ou alterar a compressão e dimensão da imagem de fato?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo compressão é diferente de redimensionamento, eu quero compressão

Comment: Então... mas o que eu perguntei é se você quer compressão do arquivo ou da imagem? Sendo da imagem, resultaria em um arquivo menor, porém com perda de qualidade. Se for só do arquivo, não tem mágica não

Comment: Eu quero compressão dos arquivos dentro da pasta, num panorama geral, a diminuição desse .zip

Answer (score 2):

Embora já esteja debatido nos comentários, apenas para formalizar, a compactação de arquivos `.jpeg` e `.jpg` (*Joint Photographic Experts Group*) não surte muito efeito porque esse formato já é uma forma compactada imagem.
Seria o equivalente a compactar um arquivo já compactado.

Este site fala sobre os tipos de imagens, incluindo sobre o formato compactado *JPEG*: https://www.infowester.com/imagens.php

Imagens com formatos não compactados, como *BMP* e *TIFF*, teriam um bom ganho ao serem compactadas.

Você pode tentar mudar o nível de compressão para melhor um pouco o ganho e diminuir um pouco mais o tamanho do arquivo. Não sei como funciona na biblioteca que você está usando, mas por exemplo o `System.IO.Compression` do `.NET` tem essa opção: [System.IO.Compression](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.compressionlevel?view=netframework-4.7.2)